# for loop in lua how to index with array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, lua, coronasdk

how can i put my looped value to an array if i have this code?

```
local data = {
 for row in db:nrows("SELECT song.id, song.title as title, artist.name as name FROM song, artist where song.artist_id = artist.id") do
    {
     song = row.title,
     artist = row.name
    }
  end
}
```

but i got this error:

```
unexpected symbol near 'for'
```

i just wanted to be look like this...

```
local data = {
 { 
   song = "HI",
   artist = "Tom"
 }
 {
   song = "Hello",
   artist = "mike"
 }
...
}
```

can anyone can help me about my situation or give some advice about it?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to do something like this, I think:

```
result = db:nrows("SELECT song.id, song.title as title, artist.name as name FROM song, artist where song.artist_id = artist.id")

data = {}
for i, row in ipairs(result) do
  data[i] = {}
  data[i].song = row.title
  data[i].artist = row.name
end
```

**Edit:** A question though: Why don't you just specify that in the SQL query and use the results as is? I.e.:

```
data = db:nrows("SELECT song.id, song.title as song, artist.name as artist FROM song, artist where song.artist_id = artist.id")
```

Comment: thanks Linus for your answer... about your question, i just want an array for the `tableView.lua` for my corona sdk..

Answer (score 2):

Having looked at the documentation dbn:rows iterates the rows and returns a table. So the {} are what are causing the problem.

local data = {}

```
for row in db:nrows("SELECT song.id, song.title as song, artist.name as artist FROM song, artist where song.artist_id = artist.id") do
  table.insert(data,row)
end
```

I have not been able to test the above as I don't have Coruna, and use a different lua system.

Reference: http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/doc/tip/doc/lsqlite3.wiki#db_nrows